# Key storage management of session keys and long term keys

Tags: keys, symmetric, key-exchange

In key management, one of the topics is key storage, I want to know where and how these keys(long-term and short-term) are stored?
For example I read that android password apps use KeyStore api to encrypt the the user passwords. I found the following steps for these kinds of apps:

```
    1.Generate a random key when the app runs the first time;
    2.When you want to store a secret, retrieve the key from KeyStore, encrypt the data with it, and then store the encrypted data in Preferences.
    When you want to read a secret, read the encrypted data from Preferences, get the key from KeyStore and then use the key to decrypt the data.
```

Now the question is how does this randomly generated key gets stored in a safe way and then retrieved?(more common question is how apps store secrets used for encryption either in windows or android or other OSs)

About short term keys like session key for example TLS protocol for this website, I found out that they are stored in memory but again how? I mean can we access that part of memory?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptoraphy.SE. Who are you, what is your aim, what is your target security, and what are your risks? Without this information this question is unclear! you can [edit] your question to clarify those.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for the advice.I completed my question as much I had information. Hope you understand what I am asking.

Comment: This question is out of scope of Crypto SE. I suggest to move it to the Security SE.

Comment: @mentallurg Migration requests are generally through flags instead of comments. However, I think that this one is too broad, key management is the subject of entire books and if there are additional security measures for session keys is implementation specific.